# wxpython shell enable uparrow to retrieve commands

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am using Shell from wx.py.shell, it is working good. But how do I enable the Python prompt like up arrow key feature. When I use arrow key inside shell, cursor goes up and down, while I want it to step through the last commands.

I see from doc that http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.py.shell.Shell-class.html#OnHistoryInsert,  it does keep track of history but how to enable it to retrieve with arrow keys?

Comment: PyShell is actually behaving exactly like IDLE in this case. You don't use the arrow key in IDLE to cycle through old commands. You can put the cursor on an old command and hit enter, which will cause the line (or block of code) to be pasted at the current prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ctrl-arrow.  The F1 key will show you some of the other special key bindings.